# Submit form using ajax. Pass url variables to coldfusion function in cfc

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, coldfusion

I am making a filter for a dashboard page with a bunch of charts being fed from an ajax call to my database and making a json struct out of it.  I am getting a little lost with the filter because basically every field is optional.  Right now I am submitting the from with jquery and formvalidator.io.  Which sends the from values to a function that originally drew my charts.  The place I am getting lost at is in my coldfusion handeler that passes the data to a coldfusion function.  How do I pass a dynamic number of arguments?

Code:

Submit form with jquery:

```js
$('#overviewFilter').formValidation({
            framework: 'bootstrap4'
        }).on("success.form.fv", function(e) {
            // Prevent form submission
            e.preventDefault();
            projectOverview();
        });
```

Json part of the projectOverview function.  I have the serializeArray() bit in there but I was just experimenting that might be way off base.

```js
function projectOverview() {
    var formString = $('#overview_filter').serializeArray();
    $.getJSON('/a_assets/ajax/a_cms.cfm',{cms_action:'task_complete_history',form_data:formString}, function (data) {
    //charts 
    });
```

Coldfusion Handeler code.  I have the #url# parameter in the function because I was experimenting.

```html
<cfif structKeyExists(url,"cms_action") and url.cms_action eq 'task_complete_history'>
    <cfobject name="cms" component="a_assets.cfc.cms">
    <cfset TaskHistoryNewComplete = cms.fnTaskHistoryNewComplete(#url#)>
    <cfoutput>#TaskHistoryNewComplete#</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Coldfusion CFC.  I have the one formData argument for now.  Each call to a function is a query that needs the values I am looking for to filter the charts.

```html
<cffunction name="fnTaskHistoryNewComplete" returntype="any" output="false">
        <cfargument name="formData" required="false">
        <cfset mydata = []>
        <cfset mydatatemp = structNew()>
        <cfset progressObj = []>
        <cfset TaskIntake = fnTaskIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Month'] = Month>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Completed'] = Completed>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Opened'] = Opened>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Late'] = Late>
            <cfset arrayAppend(progressObj, mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['progress'] = progressObj>
        <cfset userObj = []>
        <cfset TaskUserIntake = fnTaskUserIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskUserIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['UserId'] = UserRcId>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Fname'] = Fname>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Lname'] = Lname>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Assigned'] = TaskCount>
            <cfset arrayAppend(userObj,mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['users'] = userObj>
        <cfset typeObj = []>
        <cfset TaskTypeIntake = fnTaskTypeIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskTypeIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['TypeId'] = NFTypeRcId>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Name'] = NFTDescription>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['TypeCount'] = TaskCount>
            <cfset arrayAppend(typeObj,mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['types'] = typeObj>
        <cfset tagObj = []>
        <cfset TaskTagIntake = fnTaskTagIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskTagIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['TagId'] = TagRcId>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Name'] = Name>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['TagCount'] = TaskCount>
            <cfset arrayAppend(tagObj,mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['tags'] = tagObj>
        <cfset gameObj = []>
        <cfset TaskGameIntake = fnTaskGameIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskGameIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['GameId'] = GameRcId>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Name'] = GameName>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['GameCount'] = TaskCount>
            <cfset arrayAppend(gameObj,mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['games'] = gameObj>
        <cfset platformObj = []>
        <cfset TaskPlatformIntake = fnTaskPlatformIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskPlatformIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['PlatformId'] = PlatformRcId>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Name'] = Name>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['PlatformCount'] = TaskCount>
            <cfset arrayAppend(platformObj,mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['platforms'] = platformObj>
        <cfset genreObj = []>
        <cfset TaskGenreIntake = fnTaskGenreIntake()>
        <cfloop query="TaskGenreIntake">
            <cfset mydatatemp2 = structNew()>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['GenreId'] = GenreRcId>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['Name'] = Name>
            <cfset mydatatemp2['GenreCount'] = TaskCount>
            <cfset arrayAppend(genreObj,mydatatemp2)>
        </cfloop>
        <cfset mydatatemp['genres'] = genreObj>
        <cfset arrayAppend(mydata,mydatatemp)>
        <cfset data = structNew()>
        <cfset data['data'] = mydata>
        <cfset TaskHistoryNewComplete = serializeJson(mydata)>
        <cfreturn TaskHistoryNewComplete>
    </cffunction>
```

I am sure I have done this before but I can not remember for the life of me how I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Focus on each issue individually.  You state, `The place I am getting lost at is in my coldfusion handeler that passes the data to a coldfusion function.`  That's the problem at hand.  When you isolate it, you realize you have to do this sort of thing.

```
<cfargument name = "optionalArgument" default = "defaultValue">
<cfif arguments.optionalArgument is "defaultValue">
code for that argument not provided
<cfelse>
code for argument is provided
</cfif>
```

Comment: I know I could do it with a mess of CFIFs.  I was to avoid that if possible.  but it is what it is.